# Is the formula $\int_{s_0}^{s_1}a(s)\,ds=\int_{v_0}^{v_1}v\,dv$ also true for polar coordinates?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics, integration

I wonder if the formula $$\int_{s_0}^{s_1}{a(s)ds=}\int_{v_0}^{v_1}vdv$$ (with $s$ as the distance) is true in polar coordinates as well so $$\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\alpha(\theta)\,d\theta=\int_{\omega_0}^{\omega_1}\omega\, d\omega~?$$

Comment: The right hand side of the first equation can be derived from the left hand side via $ds=\frac{ds}{dt}dt = v dt $ and $a=dv/dt$. Similar analogous angular relations hold for the second equation too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it all boils down to the definitions of your quantities.

The angular acceleration $\alpha$ is defined as $$ \alpha = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \theta}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d} \omega}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d} \omega}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d}t}}_{\omega},  $$ where all the above expressions are equivalent, and in the last one I used the chain rule.

Looking at the L(eftmost)HS and R(ightmost)HS, $$\alpha = \omega\frac{\mathrm{d} \omega}{\mathrm{d}\theta} \implies \int\alpha \,\mathrm{d}\theta = \int \omega\, \mathrm{d}\omega.$$

With an overall constant of integration to be set by initial conditions, or with limits of integration.